# Как сохранить токен по ссылке с google ads, для всех страниц

Tags: php, cookie, localstorage, token

Всем добрый день, я написал такой код, что при переходе на сайт, с google ads видело в ссылке мой токен, и потом ложу его в невидимый инпут.

Но такое работает только для страницы с правильной ссылкой, типа https://site.com/order/?token=ASPKK-HHAD

И у меня нет никаких идей, как сделать так, что бы когда человек с рекламы перешел по этой ссылке, она сохранилась для всех страниц, человек же может перейти на форму, а потом полазить по сайту, а ссылку уже собьётся и трекать не получиться...

Сохраняю в куки, но так же их видно только на одной странице.

Может кто то подсказать хоть куда капать?) спасибо)

```
<?php
 
$url = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];;
 
$url_components = parse_url($url); 
 
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
 
echo '<div class="parse-youtube-link" data-url="' . $params['token'] . '"></div>';

$url_cookie = $params['token'];
$expireDate = time()+2*24*60*60;
setcookie("url_cookie", $url_cookie, $expireDate, "/" );
?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте класть в cookie

Comment: да, я пробовал, но сохраняет для одной страницы только, туда куда приходит, отредактировал код

Comment: Проверьте в заголовках ответа, отправляется ли кука
Возможно стоит использовать сессии (если вы их используете)